# dynamic row filter vector in data.table

Tags: r, vector, dynamic, data.table, rowfilter

I have a data.table -

```
DT<-data.table(ACT=c("Media","nonMedia","Media","TV"), MESSAGE = c("Standalone","other","other","Standalone"))

   ACT         MESSAGE
  Media      Standalone
  nonMedia   other
  Media      other
  TV         Standalone
```

I have 2 vectors with values:-

```
ACT=c("Media","TV")
MESSAGE = c("Standalone")
```

I have to make row level dynamic filter as these vectors keep changing. The filter will be :

```
DT[!(ACT %in% c('Media','TV')) & !(MESSAGE %in% c('Standalone')),]
```

What I have achieved till now-

```
 filter_Members<-c("ACT","MESSAGE")
 filterElements <- list()
 filterElements<-lapply(filter_Members, function(x) paste0("!(",paste0(x, " %in% ", paste0("'",get(x),"'")),")", collapse = " & "))
 filterCond <- paste0(filterElements, collapse = " & ") 
 > filterCond
   [1] "!(ACT %in% 'Media') & !(ACT %in% 'TV') & !(MESSAGE %in% 'Standalone')"
```

Issue is, if we use this condition, it gives error as it is in the form of a character vector.

> ```
>  > DT[filterCond,]
>     Error in `[.data.table`(DT, filterCond, )
> ```

Now, if we use this condition as-is BUT without the double quotes, it works-

```
DT[!(ACT %in% 'Media') & !(ACT %in% 'TV') & !(MESSAGE %in% 'Standalone'),]
```

Result -

```
 ACT     MESSAGE
nonMedia   other
```

I have tried below two ways but none worked.

```
DT[noquote(filtercond),]
DT[eval(filtercond),]
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Parse string as text: `DT[eval(parse(text = filterCond)), ]`

Comment: Worked like butter! Thank you so much !